# How is this statement a Boolean

Tags: javascript, function, boolean

I'm reading through Eloquent JS and on the chapter about High Order functions I'm having trouble understanding this code.

```
function noisy (f) {
  return function (arg) {
    console.log ("calling with" , arg ) ;
    var val = f(arg);
    console.log ("called with" ,arg, "- got",val) ;
    console.log(typeof f(arg))
    return val ;
};
}
noisy (Boolean)(0) ;
```

- how is line 4 a Boolean statement?
- What is f being used for in this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Its because inside of the inner function, `typeof f(arg)` is being called as `typeof Boolean(0)`.
- `f` is `0` which is passed to the `Boolean` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`noisy(f)` here is a function that *returns* a function.

`noisy(Boolean)` returns the function:

```
function returned(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = Boolean(arg);
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    console.log(typeof Boolean(arg));
    return val;
};
```

You then call that returned function, passing in zero. So you are essentially executing the following code:

```
console.log("calling with", 0);
var val = Boolean(0);
console.log("called with", 0, "- got", val);
console.log(typeof Boolean(0));
```

To answer your question:

- Line 4 is a Boolean expression because you passed in a type and invoked its constructor
- f is a variable defined by noisy, that is captured for use in the function returned by noisy

Comment: Thank that was a great explanation I appreciate it

Comment: Glad it helped. I'd appreciate it if you could mark the answer as answered so I can get some StackOverflow reputation =)